# Get value from dropdown using PHP

Tags: php, html-select

[image]

How can get the circled valued with PHP? 
How can get a value from drop down tag of HTML with PHP? Not the value of `value` tag.

Comment: I think you'll need Ajax for that because I don't think you can get that part, only the value (not 100% sure).

Comment: By typing instead of value.It was a very funny question. tell us what you want to do.

Comment: @ÖzgürCanKaragöz Hmm, that works too. No Ajax, nothing. Funny how I haven't thought of that.

Comment: thank you but i'm using only php in my code, i know that i get the value with using js.
if you know the procedure than tell me.

Comment: Your question is unclear... Are you trying to get the value from an HTML input, or that's a page and the dropdown is inside a form. Explain..

Comment: select class="form-control" name="product">
                            <?php
                                while ($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($value)) {
                                     # code...
                                   echo '<option name="option" value="'.($row['price']).'">'.($row['product_name']).'</option>';
                                 } 
                            
                            ?>
                        </select>

Comment: by selecting that option. There's also no "code" here, but an image of it.

Comment: @Mehdi Bounya
i'm trying to catch the value of $row['product_name'] how can i get it?

Comment: @RASHED Can't help you, I have no idea what you are trying to do...

Answer (score 0):

The data of the label in the option field is not passed to the server, so you cannot get that data without modifying the HTML too.
You could change the form simply though:

```
<option value="first">first</option>
<option value="second">second</option>
```

etc.

Comment: thank you but i have pass the other value using the "value";

Comment: you'll need to use javascript to read the label then, send it in a hidden field, or use a lookup table of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

Put the values and texts in an array. Then retrieve the needed text by using the value of the chosen option as array key.

**Try:**

```
$q_array = array(
 '1'=>'First',
 '2'=>'Second',
 '3'=>'Third',
 '4'=>'Fouth',
 '5'=>'Fifth'
);

echo $q_array[$_POST['quantity']];
```